# django implement unread items

Tags: django, django-models

I want to implement something like facebook's unread items/notifications. I have the following model currently:

```
class UnreadItems(models.Model):
    unread = models.BooleanField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type','object_id')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'unread_items'
```

Whenever someone creates a conversation/message or whatever to someone else, I created a new entry with the recipient as the target. However, creating unread is easy, but how should I do it in a managable fashion such that items will be marked as read whenever that resource is requested/viewed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use Signals for this.

Create a custom signal [set the providing argurments to be the Item accessed]

Create a signal handler that registers to that signal. In that signal hander to access the UnreadItem corresponding to that item.

When you access the Item that is linked with the UnreadItem (in the appropriate view method), you trigger the signal.

This scheme would let you isolate your logic for handling the unread aspect of it, in a central signal handler.

I presume that the reason you chose this design, is because you have multiple Item types that can be considered Unread. With this scheme, you won't have to spread the logic of handling the Unread everywhere. All the view needs to know is to trigger the Signal.

Comment: sounds logical. But sometimes, if I just want to count the unread items, I wouldn't want to set it as unread. Could it be done so for signals as compared to using a custom manager?

Comment: Explain more what you mean by 'count the unread items'? If you mean to ask that you want to count the number of unread items for a given user you can do a forward query like UnreadItems.objects.filter(user = u).count()    You can also filter it down by the content_type if you are trying to find the unread items of a given type for a user. Use the content_types framework to look up the type for a given model, and then use than in your filter query.

Comment: Remember: Signals are useful for manipulating objects (CRUD). If you just want to lookup the count, you can do that within the View

Answer (score 0):

You're going to either need to do this in the view when you get the objects for viewing, or you can make a custom manager that automatically marks it as read when you query for an object.